# Two database connection vs replication on one database

Tags: oracle, web-services, connection

Have a web service which connect to oracle database. On database side I have two database, from first I need select some information and in second database need to make some operations. 
 My question is about which is better to connect only second database and make replication by dbms or scheduler job from first  db which release x times in a day to refresh data  or make two data source on java side and after select some data from first database, connect second one to make some operations.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, I'd access only the "second" database (in which you do those *operations*) and let it acquire data it needs from the "first" database via a database link.

That can be done directly, such as

```
select some_columns from db1_table@db_link where ...
```

or, if it turns out to be way too slow and difficult to tune, create a materialized view in the second database which would then be refreshed using one of available options (a scheduled refresh might be one of the choices).

As it is primarily opinion-based answer, I presume that you'll hear other options from someone else.  Further discussion will raise the most appropriate solution to the top.

Comment: Thank you for response, yes I mean created materialized view but on "first" database table which I need don't have a primary key for check new data so my materialized view need to truncate and copy data for every run

Comment: Well that's not good. Why do you have a database table without a primary key? It's hard for us to give you meaningful advice if you're working with a non-standard architecture.

Comment: Absolutely,  I completely agree with you  but "first" database doesn't belong to me, it's vendor db and I couldn't change anything except make connection, make db link  or create replication with help of materialized view.  
So that why I asked what would be better solution for me in this situation.